# Laravel queue priority and reserved

Tags: laravel, queue

I'm getting a bit confused with laravel `--queue` option and `reserved` column (using mysql).
1- as laravel documentation has stated :

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=high,low
```

> In this example, jobs on the high queue will always be processed
>   before moving onto jobs from the low queue.

lets say i have a `high` job and multiple `low` job. job `high` get fired and because of an issue pushed back to queue to fire again after 60 seconds. what happen in this period? does job `low` get started or no?

2- Does `queue:work --daemon` work just like `queue:listen` ? I mean does it process all jobs like what `listen` do?

3- what is `reserved` column for?

Answer (score 2):

1. I can only guess here, but I assume `high` job would be retried before `low` ones. That's why you should use `tries=3(or whatever)` flag when running the worker or add `public $tries = 5;` to the Job class. Or you could take advantage of `InteractsWithQueue` trait for even finer control.
2. I believe, later Laravel versions run in daemon mode by default when you use `queue:work` command. Daemon worker processes are long lived and work faster as they don't need to restart the whole framework for every new job. The `queue:listen` command isn't even documented in the latest (5.4) version docs. The worker spawned by this command restarts itself before every job poll. Personally, I still use this, as I've got issues with memory when running daemon workers.
3. As I understand, this column is the way to mark when the specific job was started to be executed. In the `queue.php` config file you can specify when the connection should retry the job. I think the connection decides if the job should be retried by looking at `reserved` column.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no accepted answer, and I happened to search and investigate about all of these issues, let me answer them:

1. jobs from `low` will be processed, at least for 60 seconds. After 60 seconds, the job from `high` will become available, so it will be processed before of the remaining `low` jobs.
2. At writing time, March 2019, and since version 5:3, the suggested way to use queues is `queue:work`, that is the daemonized version of `queue:listen`
3. In current version there is a `reserved_at` column representing the time in which a job was assigned to a worker to process it.